# how to use _STRUCT_MCONTEXT in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

how to use  _STRUCT_MCONTEXT in swift?

in objective-c

```
#ifndef _MCONTEXT_T
#define _MCONTEXT_T
#if defined(__LP64__)
typedef _STRUCT_MCONTEXT64  *mcontext_t;
#define _STRUCT_MCONTEXT _STRUCT_MCONTEXT64
#else
typedef _STRUCT_MCONTEXT32  *mcontext_t;
#define _STRUCT_MCONTEXT    _STRUCT_MCONTEXT32
#endif
```

_STRUCT_MCONTEXT define with 64bit and 32bit

but in swift, I cant find _STRUCT_MCONTEXT, so I don't know how to use _STRUCT_MCONTEXT in swift

Comment: What is `_STRUCT_MCONTEXT`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alexander just like https://github.com/bestswifter/BSBacktraceLogger，it use _STRUCT_MCONTEXT to get what it want

Comment: Do you expect me to hunt around a code base in a foreign language, just to decode what youre trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you should use `mcontext_t`.

```
@import Darwin.machine
//In there, you will find:
public typealias mcontext_t = UnsafeMutablePointer<__darwin_mcontext64>
```

The type is determined according to the compilation target, as you’d expect from the Objective C macro.